# Problem with POST requests in JSON using HTTP Client in Android

Tags: java, android, node.js, android-studio, post

I have a button in html file when it is pressed it call the postData function in MainActivity.java

```
<script>
document.getElementById("login-button").addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    var username = document.getElementById("username").value;
    var password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    var role = document.getElementById("role").value;
    var company = document.getElementById("company").value;

    Android.postData(username, password, role, company);
});
```

MainActivity.java:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private String username;
private String password;
private String role;
private String company;
private Retrofit retrofit;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    WebView webView = findViewById(R.id.webview);
    webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(), "Android");
    webView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/index.html");


}

public class WebAppInterface {
    @JavascriptInterface
    public void postData(String username, String password, String role, String company) {
        try {
            //Test the data is fit with html input
            System.out.println("Username: " + username);
            System.out.println("Password: " + password);
            System.out.println("Role: " + role);
            System.out.println("Company: " + company);

            JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
            jsonObject.put("username", username);
            jsonObject.put("password", password);
            jsonObject.put("role", role);
            jsonObject.put("company", company);
            String jsonString = jsonObject.toString();
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                new post().executeOnExecutor(AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR, jsonString);
            } else {
                new post().execute(jsonString);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
class post extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... strings) {
        try {

            // on below line creating a url to post the data.
            URL url = new URL("http://10.0.2.2:3000/login");

            // on below line opening the connection.
            HttpURLConnection client = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

            // on below line setting method as post.
            client.setRequestMethod("POST");

            // on below line setting content type and accept type.
            client.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/json");
            client.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/json");

            // on below line setting client.
            client.setDoOutput(true);

            // on below line we are creating an output stream and posting the data.
            try (OutputStream os = client.getOutputStream()) {
                byte[] input = strings[0].getBytes("utf-8");
                os.write(input, 0, input.length);
            }

            // on below line creating and initializing buffer reader.
            try (BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(
                    new InputStreamReader(client.getInputStream(), "utf-8"))) {

                // on below line creating a string builder.
                StringBuilder response = new StringBuilder();

                // on below line creating a variable for response line.
                String responseLine = null;

                // on below line writing the response
                while ((responseLine = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    response.append(responseLine.trim());
                }
            }

        } catch (Exception e) {

            // on below line handling the exception.
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

}

After submit button Logcat show:

```
2023-06-15 05:21:08.684   505-505   AutofillManager         com.example.myapplication            V  requestHideFillUi(null): anchor = null
2023-06-15 05:21:08.763   505-2113  System.out              com.example.myapplication            I  Username: 1
2023-06-15 05:21:08.763   505-2113  System.out              com.example.myapplication            I  Password: 1
2023-06-15 05:21:08.763   505-2113  System.out              com.example.myapplication            I  Role: Company
2023-06-15 05:21:08.763   505-2113  System.out              com.example.myapplication            I  Company: Company 1
```

This is my server.js:

```
app.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    const { username, password, role, company } = req.body;
    // Perform your login logic here
    // For demonstration purposes, let's assume the username is "admin" and password is "password"
    console.log(username, password, role, company);

    if (role === 'Company' && company === 'Company 2' &&
        username === 'admin2' && password === 'password') {

        res.json({ success: true, message: 'org2CreateUser.html' });
    }
    if (role === 'Company' && company === 'Company 1' &&
        username === 'admin1' && password === 'password') {

        res.json({ success: true, message: 'org1CreateUser.html' });
    }
    if (role === 'Employer') {
        credentials.forEach(element => {
            if(element.username === username && element.password == password) {
                res.json({ success: true, message: 'upload.html' });
                return;
            }
        });
        res.status(401).json({ success: false, message: 'Invalid username or password' });
    }
});
app.listen(3000, () => {
    console.log('Server is running on port 3000');
});
```

The problem is i dont see the console.log(username, password, role, company); respone in console.log of server.When i use curl to test server it show normally:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{
  "username": "admin",
  "password": "password",
  "role": "Company",
  "company": "Company 1"
}' http://localhost:3000/login
```

I dont know the json is send to the server or not. I use Android Studio in ubuntu vmware and connect my phone with usb debug.

Comment: You should log much more. Also in the async task and catch blocks.

Answer (score 1):

Try to check the communication between your Android application and the server.

See if the `AsyncTask` is being executing properly.

Check internet permissions in your AndroidManifest.xml file

```xml
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

If its not in localhost, check if your server is accessible from your Android device or simulator. Make sure you're using the correct IP address or hostname and port number to connect to the server.

Instead of `AsyncTask`, consider using `HttpURLConnection`, `OkHttp`, or libraries like `Retrofit` or `Volley`.

Retrofit example:

- Add dependency to your build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0' // if you're using JSON
```

- Create instance and define an interface for your API:

```java
Retrofit retrofit = new Retrofit.Builder()
    .baseUrl("http://10.0.2.2:3000/")
    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()) 
    .build();

// API interface
interface MyApi {
    @POST("login")
    Call<ResponseBody> login(@Body JsonObject body); // replace with the request body type
}

MyApi myApi = retrofit.create(MyApi.class);
```

- Use the Retrofit to call the API in `postData`:

```java
public void postData(String username, String password, String role, String company) {
    try {
        JsonObject body = new JsonObject();
        body.addProperty("username", username);
        body.addProperty("password", password);
        body.addProperty("role", role);
        body.addProperty("company", company);

        Call<ResponseBody> call = myApi.login(body);
        call.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {
                if (response.isSuccessful()) {
                    // Handle successful response
                    // ...
                } else {
                    // Handle unsuccessful response
                    // ...
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {
                // Handle network failure
                // ...
            }
        });
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for suggest, when i changed the 10.0.2.2 to my ipv4 it is now working.